# Prove that $\prod\limits_i(1+2\alpha_{i})\prod\limits_j(1-2\beta_{j})<\prod\limits_i(1+2x_{i})\prod\limits_j(1-2y_{j})$

Tags: analysis, inequality

> Let $m,n\in N^{+}$ and $i=1,2,\ldots,n,\;j=1,2,\ldots,m\,$ and $\,x_{i},\alpha_{i},y_{j},\beta_{j}$ be real numbers such that $$0\le x_{i}<\alpha_{i}<\dfrac{1}{2},\qquad0\le y_{j}<\beta_{j}<\dfrac{1}{2}$$
> Assume that $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+x_{i})\prod_{j=1}^{m}(1-y_{j})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+\alpha_{i})\prod_{j=1}^{m}(1-\beta_{j})$$
>
> Show that
> $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+2\alpha_{i})\prod_{j=1}^{m}(1-2\beta_{j})<\prod_{i=1}^{n}(1+2x_{i})\prod_{j=1}^{m}(1-2y_{j})$$

this problem seems it's nice.
my idea:
the condition can
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(1+x_{i})}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\ln{(1-y_{j})}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(1+\alpha_{i})}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\ln{(1-\beta_{j})}$$
and prove
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(1+2\alpha_{i})}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\ln{(1-2\beta_{j})}<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(1+2x_{i})}+\sum_{j=1}^{m}\ln{(1-2y_{j})}$$
then I can't.Thank you

Comment: I suspect there is a typo: the first $\ln$ term in the last equation should be $\ln(1+2\alpha_i)$, right?

Comment: why the downvote ?

Comment: It seems to me that there's _more than one_ typo in the question (didn't downvote, though).

Comment: Have you tried to apply Karamata's inequality?